# Commented out code still executes in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

The code continually segues into the next view controller...even with performSegueWithIdentifier() commented out. It doesn't matter if the text fields are blank (which should prompt up an alert) or if the username/password is entered correctly, it just segues anyway.

I've tried Clean -> Build -> Run, as well as removing the view controller in Storyboard and re-adding a new one. What's the issue here?

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userEmail, password: userPassword) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            //If user is found in Parse, log in
            if user != nil {
                var successAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Logged In", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                successAlert.show()

                //Transition to FacebookViewController
                //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginToFacebookSegue", sender: self)
            }

            //Display warning - incorrect login
            var warningAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Try again", message: "Username/password incorrect", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Dismiss")
            warningAlert.show()
        }
```

Comment: how do you have the segue attached? For example, if you attached it to a button, it will be automatically executed. You need to put it between the view controllers, then call it.

Comment: Clean the folder with Shift+Alt+Cmd+K so it will clean every cache and is stronger than common Clean Build. Sometimes it helps.

Comment: Ah, I did attach it to a button. Can you elaborate on how to put it between view controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that since your segue is attached to a `UIButton`, it is automatically called when the button is pressed. Your block is never really getting called. To fix this, drag your connection from view controller to view controller. Make sure you are **zoomed out in the storyboard**, then just create the connection (option dragging from a black spot in the view controller itself not the button). Make sure to give your segue an identifier.

Then call `performSegueWithIdentifier` when you need to run the segue.